# Running Tasks Automatically on Windows 7 Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-7, cron, windows-scripting

I have a CSV that my computer downloads every 15 minutes automatically.  I then want to automatically upload this CSV to my Google Docs account using their API.

I figure I can write a simple VBScript that pulls the CSV file from it's location and POSTs to the Google Docs API but my question is how do I set the script to run every 15 minutes in the Windows 7 environment.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: the Windows task scheduler.  [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

EDIT: Eh, probably a poor link.  [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) is more specific.  You can also do it from the command line with the at command.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the script that it has poor monitor service. If you will write a windows service it can be resumed and logged automatically.